# How do I confirm ufw is working using nmap from the local system?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, nmap

I have enabled Uncomplicated Firewall on Ubuntu Focal:

```
# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

And yet, it doesn't seem to be blocking anything:

```
# ip -o -4 address
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3\       valid_lft 77618sec preferred_lft 77618sec

# nmap 127.0.0.1 10.0.2.15
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-17 15:11 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000030s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh

Nmap scan report for dummyhost (10.0.2.15)
Host is up (0.0000030s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 2 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

Apparently `nmap` doesn't traverse the firewall when scanning and running on the same host. Is there a way to `nmap` scan public addresses on the local system as if I were scanning from a remote system?

Comment: if you're nmapping yourself from yourself, it never traverses past the firewall in a way that a reflection or response wouldn't also be ACCEPTed - `ufw` adds a `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` state accepted rule so that responses to traffic YOU initiate from your machine actually work.  Which is Standard Behavior.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. How do I tell nmap to hit the firewall?

Comment: You don't, if you originate from your own system.  You need to nmap from another system on the network to test if the firewall actually works.